# CSS positioning boxes using ul li div

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-lists

**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE BELOW**

I want to make the following CSS layout and currently im using UL to float the LI left. The problem is the 2 rectangles wont stay on either side. And not sure how to position the bottom 2 rectangles.

[image]
I tried wrapped a div in the middle of the UL LI but thats not proper markup. 
Please can you help? Possibly a JSFIDDLE example if you could?
Thanks

**EDIT: Here you go, [jsfiddle.net/fpqxy/1](http://jsfiddle.net/fpqxy/1/) boxes 2 and 3 are in position but 4 and 5 need to be below them. Then box 6 needs to move accross with 7 and 8 remaining at the bottom. –**

Comment: I'd use a `<table>` with colspan and rowspan. I know you might not want to use `<table>` as a layout element but this is exactly a "table layout".

Comment: It's not clear from your diagram which elements are which.  Are the 2 tall rectangles the divs you want either side?  And the 4 smaller ones are the lis? ... Would you ever want a different number of lis? It would also help people answer if you post your html - perhaps as a link to a http://jsfiddle.net/ page?

Comment: Bare with me ill post some HTML.. I think i should just make DIV wrappers and make them relative and anything within as absolute right? and then sack off the whole ul li idea.

Comment: Here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/fpqxy/1/ boxes 2 and 3 are in position but 4 and 5 need to be below them. Then box 6 needs to move accross with 7 and 8 remaining at the bottom.

Comment: do i just create seperate ULs ????

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the below fiddle and demo

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fpqxy/5

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fpqxy/5/embedded/result/

[image]

Comment: box 8 seems to move when i resize the window?

Answer (score 1):

Tables, pah!

Group boxes 2-5 in a wrapper element, then your flow will be:

1, 2-5, 6, 7, 8

This will only work if all your boxes are the same height within a given 'row'.

Hope this helps.